# How to plot variation over time in three different groups, in a "graphpad prism" style?

Tags: r, ggplot2, compare, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have this dataset:

```
structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15), ttt1_1 = c(0, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 
130, 160, 240, 320, 450), ttt1_2 = c(0, 17, 22, 34, 50, 50, 65, 
75, 90, 120, 160, 200, 300, 400, 500), ttt1_3 = c(0, 19, 25, 
36, 47, 60, 70, 86, 110, 130, 195, 240, 360, 480, 650), ttt2_1 = c(0, 
45, 60, 90, 120, 150, 210, 245, 280, 315, 455, 560, 720, 960, 
1350), ttt2_2 = c(0, 51, 66, 102, 130, 150, 228, 262, 315, 420, 
560, 700, 900, 1200, 1500), ttt2_3 = c(0, 57, 75, 108, 141, 180, 
245, 301, 385, 455, 683, 840, 1080, 1440, 1950), ttt3_1 = c(0, 
90, 120, 180, 240, 300, 420, 490, 560, 630, 910, 1120, 1440, 
1920, 2700), ttt3_2 = c(0, 102, 132, 204, 300, 300, 455, 525, 
630, 840, 1120, 1400, 1800, 2400, 3000), ttt3_3 = c(0, 114, 150, 
216, 282, 360, 490, 602, 770, 910, 1365, 1680, 2160, 2880, 3900
)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like this:

```
> datapoids
   time ttt1_1 ttt1_2 ttt1_3 ttt2_1 ttt2_2 ttt2_3 ttt3_1 ttt3_2 ttt3_3
1     1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2     2     15     17     19     45     51     57     90    102    114
3     3     20     22     25     60     66     75    120    132    150
4     4     30     34     36     90    102    108    180    204    216
5     5     40     50     47    120    130    141    240    300    282
6     6     50     50     60    150    150    180    300    300    360
7     7     60     65     70    210    228    245    420    455    490
8     8     70     75     86    245    262    301    490    525    602
9     9     80     90    110    280    315    385    560    630    770
10   10     90    120    130    315    420    455    630    840    910
11   11    130    160    195    455    560    683    910   1120   1365
12   12    160    200    240    560    700    840   1120   1400   1680
13   13    240    300    360    720    900   1080   1440   1800   2160
14   14    320    400    480    960   1200   1440   1920   2400   2880
15   15    450    500    650   1350   1500   1950   2700   3000   3900
```

This dataset represent variation over time (first column = elapsed time in days) of the weight of 9 individuals (3 individuals in 3 differents groups: ttt1, ttt2, ttt3).

First, i am trying to plot this kind of graph (done with Graphpad Prism):
[image: plot with graphpad]

But so far, the only thing I managed to get is this (I can only plot one column at a time, where I want to plot the mean of 3 columns (ttt1_1, ttt1_2, ttt1_3 for example), and do it for my three groups (ttt1, ttt2, ttt3).

```
ggplot(data=datapoids, aes(x=time,y=ttt3_1)) +
  geom_point(size=2)
```

Which give me:
[plot with ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6635.png)

Any idea how I can get with ggplot2 what I have with GraphPad?
Any kind of advice would be of a great help!

---

### Update 1

I changed the way my dataframe is organized to be like this:

```
> dput(head(datapoids, 60))
structure(list(time = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15), group = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3), m1 = c(0, 0, 0, 15, 45, 90, 20, 60, 120, 30, 90, 180, 
40, 120, 240, 50, 150, 300, 60, 210, 420, 70, 245, 490, 80, 280, 
560, 90, 315, 630, 130, 455, 910, 160, 560, 1120, 240, 720, 1440, 
320, 960, 1920, 450, 1350, 2700), m2 = c(0, 0, 0, 17, 51, 102, 
22, 66, 132, 34, 102, 204, 50, 130, 300, 50, 150, 300, 65, 228, 
455, 75, 262, 525, 90, 315, 630, 120, 420, 840, 160, 560, 1120, 
200, 700, 1400, 300, 900, 1800, 400, 1200, 2400, 500, 1500, 3000
), m3 = c(0, 0, 0, 19, 57, 114, 25, 75, 150, 36, 108, 216, 47, 
141, 282, 60, 180, 360, 70, 245, 490, 86, 301, 602, 110, 385, 
770, 130, 455, 910, 195, 683, 1365, 240, 840, 1680, 360, 1080, 
2160, 480, 1440, 2880, 650, 1950, 3900)), row.names = c(NA, -45L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
> datapoids
# A tibble: 45 x 5
    time group    m1    m2    m3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     0     0     0
 2     1     2     0     0     0
 3     1     3     0     0     0
 4     2     1    15    17    19
 5     2     2    45    51    57
 6     2     3    90   102   114
 7     3     1    20    22    25
 8     3     2    60    66    75
 9     3     3   120   132   150
10     4     1    30    34    36
# ... with 35 more rows
```

With column 1 representing elapsing time, column 2 is the group, column 3-4-5 is the three individuals in each group.

So far I managed to get the three set of data on the graph but only for 1 individuals at each time, I can't get the mean +/- SD...

```
ggplot(datapoids, aes(x = time, y = m1, group = group)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[three groups but only one individual per group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocOAX.png)

---

### Update 2

Ok here is another update.
I have formated my dataset to look like this:

```
> print.data.frame(datapoids)
    weight group time
1        0     1    1
2        0     1    1
3        0     1    1
4        0     2    1
5        0     2    1
6        0     2    1
7        0     3    1
8        0     3    1
9        0     3    1
10      15     1    2
11      17     1    2
12      19     1    2
13      45     2    2
14      51     2    2
15      57     2    2
16      90     3    2
17     102     3    2
18     114     3    2
19      20     1    3
20      22     1    3
21      25     1    3
22      60     2    3
23      66     2    3
24      75     2    3
25     120     3    3
26     132     3    3
27     150     3    3
28      30     1    4
29      34     1    4
30      36     1    4
31      90     2    4
32     102     2    4
33     108     2    4
34     180     3    4
35     204     3    4
36     216     3    4
37      40     1    5
38      50     1    5
39      47     1    5
40     120     2    5
41     130     2    5
42     141     2    5
43     240     3    5
44     300     3    5
45     282     3    5
46      50     1    6
47      50     1    6
48      60     1    6
49     150     2    6
50     150     2    6
51     180     2    6
52     300     3    6
53     300     3    6
54     360     3    6
55      60     1    7
56      65     1    7
57      70     1    7
58     210     2    7
59     228     2    7
60     245     2    7
61     420     3    7
62     455     3    7
63     490     3    7
64      70     1    8
65      75     1    8
66      86     1    8
67     245     2    8
68     262     2    8
69     301     2    8
70     490     3    8
71     525     3    8
72     602     3    8
73      80     1    9
74      90     1    9
75     110     1    9
76     280     2    9
77     315     2    9
78     385     2    9
79     560     3    9
80     630     3    9
81     770     3    9
82      90     1   10
83     120     1   10
84     130     1   10
85     315     2   10
86     420     2   10
87     455     2   10
88     630     3   10
89     840     3   10
90     910     3   10
91     130     1   11
92     160     1   11
93     195     1   11
94     455     2   11
95     560     2   11
96     683     2   11
97     910     3   11
98    1120     3   11
99    1365     3   11
100    160     1   12
101    200     1   12
102    240     1   12
103    560     2   12
104    700     2   12
105    840     2   12
106   1120     3   12
107   1400     3   12
108   1680     3   12
109    240     1   13
110    300     1   13
111    360     1   13
112    720     2   13
113    900     2   13
114   1080     2   13
115   1440     3   13
116   1800     3   13
117   2160     3   13
118    320     1   14
119    400     1   14
120    480     1   14
121    960     2   14
122   1200     2   14
123   1440     2   14
124   1920     3   14
125   2400     3   14
126   2880     3   14
127    450     1   15
128    500     1   15
129    650     1   15
130   1350     2   15
131   1500     2   15
132   1950     2   15
133   2700     3   15
134   3000     3   15
135   3900     3   15
```

```
> dput(head(datapoids, 10000000))
structure(list(weight = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 17, 
19, 45, 51, 57, 90, 102, 114, 20, 22, 25, 60, 66, 75, 120, 132, 
150, 30, 34, 36, 90, 102, 108, 180, 204, 216, 40, 50, 47, 120, 
130, 141, 240, 300, 282, 50, 50, 60, 150, 150, 180, 300, 300, 
360, 60, 65, 70, 210, 228, 245, 420, 455, 490, 70, 75, 86, 245, 
262, 301, 490, 525, 602, 80, 90, 110, 280, 315, 385, 560, 630, 
770, 90, 120, 130, 315, 420, 455, 630, 840, 910, 130, 160, 195, 
455, 560, 683, 910, 1120, 1365, 160, 200, 240, 560, 700, 840, 
1120, 1400, 1680, 240, 300, 360, 720, 900, 1080, 1440, 1800, 
2160, 320, 400, 480, 960, 1200, 1440, 1920, 2400, 2880, 450, 
500, 650, 1350, 1500, 1950, 2700, 3000, 3900), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
    "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-135L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And with this:

```
ggplot(datapoids, aes(x = time, y = weight)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group), position="identity") +  
  geom_point()
```

I managed to get this (it is not mean +/- SD yet):

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Since all of the initial measured weights are zero, is the first time "day zero" - that is, is the first measurement done when no time has elapsed yet?

Comment: yes, first time point is day 0 ; and yes first measurement where done before starting treatment

Comment: `ggplot(datapoids, aes(x = as.numeric(time), y = weight, color = group)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1))` for the first part.

Comment: thanks for pointing the "stat_sumary" function, I just changed the position of "colour = group" in the stat_sumary part and it worked! I'll post it in an answer under the first post if that's ok and create another post for my second question (ploting non linear regression between groups and compare them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Axeman, I found the answer:

```
ggplot(datapoids, aes(x = time, y = weight)) +
  stat_summary(aes(color = group), fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1), geom="pointrange", position = "identity")
```

Where `fun.data="mean_sdl"` shows the mean +/- a constante time standard derivation and `fun.args = list(mult=1)` defines the constante (here = 1).

And I finally got what I wanted 
[image: stat_summary]

I just need to find how to (work in progress):

- change color of each group
- change symbol for each group
- add a small bar above and under the error bar

---

### Update

Here is the final result:
[image: Graphpad style achieved]

With:

```
ggplot(datapoidsmono, aes(x = time, y = weight)) +
  stat_summary(aes(color = group), fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1), geom="errorbar", position = "identity", size=0.5, width=0.2, show.legend = T) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", size=3, aes(shape=group,colour=group)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Days after injection") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Weight (g)", limits=c(0, 4000), breaks = seq(0, 4000,500)) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size = 12),axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", size = 12),axis.title = element_text(size =15, face="bold"),plot.title = element_text(size =20, face = "bold"),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#F1F1F1"),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "blue", "red")) +
  ggtitle("Weight variation over time") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score -1):

My equation search turned up the sigmoidal type Magnetic Saturation equation as giving the best fit to the average weights for the three groups. Initial elapsed time of zero is used for the first time measurement per your comment.

Weight = a * x * (1.0 + b * exp(c * ElapsedDays))

My fitting results for each group are as follows:

For group 1, parameters are:

```
a =  8.2069429067318076E+00
b =  3.4803188790045243E-02
c =  3.3342423727900505E-01
```

with R-squared = 0.997 and RMSE = 7.96

[image: plot1]

For group 2, parameters are:

```
a =  2.7849455860678560E+01
b =  4.7404034036124171E-02
c =  2.9879802065164002E-01
```

with  R-squared = 0.999 and RMSE = 12.85

[image: plot2]

for group 3, parameters are:

```
a =  5.6346090778919425E+01
b =  4.5307611859092961E-02
c =  3.0096010027034203E-01
```

with R-squared = 0.999 and RMSE = 25.941

[image: plot3]

Comment: I will point out that all have similar parameters for b and c, with parameter a (acting as amplitude) being different for all three. This is a strong hint that there might be some simple, now-not-so-hidden relationship between time and weight for all groups.

Comment: thanks @JamesPhillips. I have generated the data to show what I want to do with future incoming measures but these data are totaly random... so my question is more about how to draw the plot and compare the slopes than about the data itself... thanks again anyway!

Comment: @Axeman per the Original Poster's comment to this answer, yes.